# Converting unix timestamp before sending it by json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, date

First of all thanks for taking the time to look into this.

I store the date in my database as a unix timestamp and when I get all the info using:

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    /* return the posts in the JSON format */
    return json_encode($posts);
```

The date is available only as a unix timestamp when I try to get it using the following:

```
var postHandler = function(postsJSON) {
 $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {
alert(post.date);
}
}
```

Is there a way to convert it to readable date before sending it by JSON? Or even afterwards?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: did either of the answers resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JavaScript.

```
alert(new Date(post.date))
```

Note: It's the best to pass it all the way in UNIX timestamp format until rendered, because:

1. It keeps the payload low, since you're transferring an integer and not a string.
2. It enables you to use the timestamp in different ways on the client without having to parse it again. e.g. `Date.now()/1000 - post.date` will give you the number of seconds since the post was created, and so on.
3. UNIX timestamp is not timezone-sensitive. When rendered on client, it'll be in the local timezone and format. If you render it on the server, it'll be in server's timezone and use server's locale settings.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, from the PHP side you could do it like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row['your_date_field'] = date('r', $row['your_date_field']);
    $posts[] = $row;
}
```

(You can customize the format string passed to `date()` as you please; `'r'` was just a simple default.)

---

From the Javascript side, you could do it like this:

```
new Date(post.date);
```

which when rendered to a string will format as the default date format, or you can use other methods on the `Date` object to get other formats.

---

Which method you use is up to you, but as dragon points out, doing it client-side is often nicer since it both reduces data transmitted and gives you more flexibility without having to parse a string.

Comment: I want to pick them both as the best answer, but unfortunately I can't! So thanks both for your answers. This helped me solve my problem! :)

Comment: No worries - it's not like I need the rep. :)